# Looking for the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices

Given is a symmetric tridiagonal $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$ of the following form:
$A=\begin{Bmatrix}
0 & a_{1}  &  &  & \\ 
a_{1} & 0  &a_{2}  &   & \\ 
 & a_{2} & 0  &\ddots  & \\ 
 &  &\ddots  &\ddots  & a_{n-1} \\ 
 &  & & a_{n-1} & 0
\end{Bmatrix}$

I am struggling with showing that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, that $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue too.

Well, first i tried to see how the characteristic polynomial looks like for the cases $n=2,3$. Then i saw in Wikipedia that there exists a recursive formula for the determinant, namely for computing the determinant $\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda &a_{1}  &  &  & \\ 
a_{1} &-\lambda  &a_{2}  &  & \\ 
 &a_{2}  &-\lambda  & \ddots & \\ 
 &  &\ddots  &\ddots  & a_{n-1} \\ 
 &  &  &a_{n-1}  &-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}$ it will be $\Delta _{n}=(-\lambda)\Delta _{n-1} - (a_{n-2})^{2}\Delta_{n-2}$.

Unfortunately, i am stuck in the last step of the induction... Can anybody help me, please? Is this the correct approach?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use induction to show that for a $(n\times n)$ matrix $A_n$, the eigenvalue must satisfy: 
$$ \lambda^2 - \sum_{i=2}^n a_i^2 = 0$$
This will automatically show that $-\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint.* You don't need mathematical induction. Let $D=D^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots)$. What is $D^{-1}AD$?